# Don't write if string is longer than a number

Tags: javascript, html

The user, if length's string is over 12 characters, can't write.This is my script ("mat" is the text field).

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("mat").onchange = function() {
    if ((document.getElementById("mat").value.length) > 12) {
      document.getElementById("mat").value = document.getElementById("mat").value.substring(0, 12);
    }
  }
}
```

This code works properly, but the characters over 12 characters are deleted only if the text field it is no longer selected.
How can I do?

Comment: Is it a `<textarea>` or an `<input type="text">`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the `maxLength` property?

```html
<input type="text" maxLength="12">
```

As of HTML 5, the `textarea` object also supports it:

```html
<textarea maxLength="12"></textarea>
```

Comment: UV - The obvious solution :)

Comment: UV Facepalm... sometimes the right solution is the easiest

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, instead of the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event. The `change` event only fires when the element is blurred, while the `input` event is fired on every change the user makes.

```js
var mat = document.getElementById("mat");

mat.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if ((mat.value.length) > 12) {
    mat.value = mat.value.substring(0, 12);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="mat">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `input` instead of `onchange`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("mat").oninput = function() {
    if ((document.getElementById("mat").value.length) > 12) {
      document.getElementById("mat").value = document.getElementById("mat").value.substring(0, 12);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mat" />
```